# Unable to install pointcloud_to_laserscan ROS Indigo

Tags: ros, kinect, pointcloud-to-laserscan, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install pointcloud_to_laserscan package in ROS Indigo running in Ubuntu 14.04. When I add the source from git repo and catkin_make I get the following error.

```
root@ramkumar-Inspiron-7720:/home/ramkumar/catkinws# catkin_make
Base path: /home/ramkumar/catkinws
Source space: /home/ramkumar/catkinws/src
Build space: /home/ramkumar/catkinws/build
Devel space: /home/ramkumar/catkinws/devel
Install space: /home/ramkumar/catkinws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/ramkumar/catkinws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/ramkumar/catkinws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/ramkumar/catkinws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/ramkumar/catkinws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/ramkumar/catkinws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/ramkumar/catkinws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.11
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 7 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - p3dx_control
-- ~~  - depthimage_to_laserscan
-- ~~  - pointcloud_to_laserscan
-- ~~  - openni_tracker
-- ~~  - rosaria
-- ~~  - p3dx_description
-- ~~  - p3dx_gazebo
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'p3dx_control'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ua_ros_p3dx/p3dx_control)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'depthimage_to_laserscan'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(depthimage_to_laserscan-indigo-devel)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'pointcloud_to_laserscan'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(pointcloud_to_laserscan)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "tf2_sensor_msgs"
with any of the following names:

tf2_sensor_msgsConfig.cmake
tf2_sensor_msgs-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "tf2_sensor_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
set "tf2_sensor_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
If "tf2_sensor_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
pointcloud_to_laserscan/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ramkumar/catkinws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ramkumar/catkinws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

Please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202078/unable-to-install-pointcloud_to_laserscan-ros-indigo/) by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2015-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As always: what have you tried yourself, and what didn't work?

The error message is particularly clear: `catkin` (or actually `cmake`) cannot find the package `tf2_sensor_msgs`. Do you have that package installed?

It is always a good idea to first do a `rosdep check --from-paths src --ignore-src` from your `/path/to/catkin_ws` directory before trying to compile packages you just cloned from some vcs repository.

---

Also: it would seem `pointcloud_to_laserscan` has been released into Indigo (see the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan?distro=indigo) page). I would recommend to install the Debians instead of building from source, unless you have a specific reason.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) on 2015-01-29**:
Thanks. I have done that and got it working. forgot to close the post. sorry.

**Comment by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) on 2015-01-29**:
What do u mean by installing the Debians. I am a newbie. please help.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-30**:
Just install the binary distribution? `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-pointcloud-to-laserscan`?

**Comment by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) on 2015-01-30**:
I solved that problem. it requires the PointCloud2 data to be published in /cloud_in topic and that node will publish the laserscan data in /scan. after i publish the pointcloud data i get the resultant scan data full of only 'Inf' and hence no plot in rviz. Any idea @gvdhoom Thanks in advance!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-30**:
Any new questions should go in new questions. Don't hijack this one (even if it is your own).
If question answered, please click the check mark.